# How to add a class to the sibling ul of a anchor tag depending on the current window url?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a dynamic sidebar on Drupal 8. I made a function to get the href of an anchor tag and if matches the window.location.href, it adds a class to the anchor tag. However, I need to add that class the sibling ul of a anchor tag.

I have try to add the class to the ul with jquery using the siblings(), next(), find() methods but I haven't been able to add the class to sibling ul of the a tag.

HTML

```
<div class="aside--sidebar">                   
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="/en/alcool-drogue-et-jeu" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/24" class="sidebar-link--opened">Menu Link 1</a>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="sidebar-link--opened">Submenu-sidebar 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="sidebar-link--opened">Submenu-sidebar 2</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

  <li>
   <a href="/en/services-prehospitaliers" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/38" class="has--content sidebarlink-with--content">Menu Link 2</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" class="sidebar-link--opened">Submenu-sidebar 3</a>
   </li>
  </ul>

  <li>
   <a href="/en/conseil-d-administration" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/14">Menu Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/en/jeunesse" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/26">Menu Link 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="/en/espace-soins-infirmiers" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/37" class="has--content sidebarlink-with--content">Menu Link 5</a>
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="/en/services-prehospitaliers" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/38" class="sidebarlink-with--content">test link</a>
   </li>
</ul>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
var sideBarUl = $('.aside--sidebar ul li');
        sideBarUl.each(function(){
            if($(this).children("ul").length) {
                $(this).find('a').addClass('sidebarlink-with--content');
            }
        });

        $(function(){
            var sideBarLinkContent = $('.sidebarlink-with--content');
            var currentWindowUrl = window.location.href;

            for ( var i = 0; i < sideBarLinkContent.length; i++) {
                if(sideBarLinkContent[i].href == currentWindowUrl){
                    sideBarLinkContent[i].className = 'sidebar-link--opened';
                }
            }
        });
```

I am just to add class to the current anchor tag that matches with window url but I an to add the class to its sibling ul to change the display to block.

Comment: It looks like your html has syntax errors. You can't use the `<` character in attribute names; replace it with `&lt;` (which will be rendered as `<`). E.g. `"<front>"` becomes `"&lt;front>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few errors in your js but it mostly right.

ok here is what i found first in the first each function where you check if li has children should

```
        // not if($(this).children("ul").length) but
         if($(this).children("ul").length> 0) { 
            $(this).find('a:not([href=""])').addClass('sidebarlink-with--content');
        }
```

second is when you validate the href is also wrong.

what your are doing is checking if

```
(relative) /en/services-prehospitaliers ==(full) www.xxx.com/en/services-prehospitaliers
```

which is wrong becouse the href contain the full url where sideBarLinkContent[i].href contain only the relative part it should be

```
             for ( var i = 0; i < sideBarLinkContent.length; i++) {
                if(currentWindowUrl.indexOf( sideBarLinkContent[i].href) != -1){
                    sideBarLinkContent[i].className = 'sidebar-link--opened';
                }
            }
```